# How to change the multi dimentional array to individual

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [store_id] => 2
        [store_str] => Andrew Brennan
        [supplier_id] => 51
        [supplier_str] => Dyson
        [brand_id] => 4
        [brand_str] => Dyson
        [category_id] => 2
        [category_str] => SDA
        [category_short_name] => SDA
        [added_by] => 1
        [inserted_on] => 1351664553
        [status] => 1
        [status_str] => Active
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [store_id] => 4
        [store_str] => Berney Crossan & Sons Ltd
        [supplier_id] => 51
        [supplier_str] => Dyson
        [brand_id] => 4
        [brand_str] => Dyson
        [category_id] => 2
        [category_str] => SDA
        [category_short_name] => SDA
        [added_by] => 1
        [inserted_on] => 1351664553
        [status] => 1
        [status_str] => Active
    ) )
```

But I want to display them as like individual arrays like $store_arr,$sup_arr,$cat_arr,$brand_arr.Means If I print $store_arr it should be like

```
Array(
    [2] => Andrew Brennan
    [4] => Berney Crossan & Sons Ltd
)
```

Like this way all the other arrays should be.I tried like

```
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
    foreach($v as $key=>$value) {
        $store_arr[$key['store_id']] = $key['store_str'];
    }
}
```

But it giving me ir-relavent data array.Can anyone suggest me How to get that.Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? You had an extra level of looping that wasn't needed.

```
foreach ($result as $store) {
  $id = $store['store_id'];
  $store_arr[$id] = $store['store_str'];
  $sup_arr[$id] = $store['supplier_str'];
  $cat_arr[$id] = $store['category_str'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Really superb..Worked smoothly.Thanku @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Umm..... Do you mean something like this?

```
foreach ($result as $i => $arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new[$key][$i]=$value;
  }
} 

var_dump($new['store_str']);
```

result

```
Array(
    [0] => Andrew Brennan
    [1] => Berney Crossan & Sons Ltd
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($result as $item) {

    $store_arr[$item['store_id']] = $item['store_str'];
}
```